# Is it possible to enable code folding for x86 assembly language in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, masm

In Visual Studio 2010, is it possible to enable code folding for assembly language procedures? I'm trying to find a way to expand/collapse procedures in MASM, like this one:

```
moveNextDigitIntoX PROC
    ;Is it possible to enable code folding in Visual Studio so that procedures like this one will be collapsible?
        mov eax, 10;
        ret;
moveNextDigitIntoX ENDP
```

Comment: There must be some way to make specific sections of code expandable/collapsible.